# Running Python in VBA where there are spaces in execution path

Tags: python, excel, vba, path, spaces

I wrote a Python script to perform calculations which I want to run via Excel VBA and display the results in Excel. To be usable for different users I am trying to write a code that will generate the paths to the Python execution and Python scripts based on the usernames they enter since that is the only thing that will change in the path.

Some people have a space in their username which causes problems when trying to run Python in the command prompt.

There are similar questions but I have not found a solution. I tried adding triple double quotations at the beginning and end of the execution path e.g.

```
"""C:\Users\Claire Watson\anaconda3\python.exe"""
```

The result in the command prompt was something like 'C:\Users\Claire' is not recognized.  This does however work for the Python script path.

I also saw that adding a ^ before the space could help e.g.

```
"""C:\Users\Claire^ Watson\anaconda3\python.exe"""
```

or

```
"C:\Users\Claire^ Watson\anaconda3\python.exe"
```

The result is that command prompt says C:\Users\Claire: can't open file 'Watson\anaconda3\python.exe: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I also tried removing some quotes but then it states that there is a syntax error or it cannot find the path.

My code:

```vb
Dim objShell As Object
Dim pythonexe As String
Dim pythonscript As String
Dim Username As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Username = "Some name with or without spaces" 'dependent on the user input

pythonscript = """C:\Users\" & Username & "\........py"""

If InStr(Username, " ") > 0 Then ' Checks to see if there are spaces in username

    pythonexe = """C:\Users\" & Username & "\anaconda3\python.exe"""
    
    objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & pythonexe & " " & pythonscript
Else

     pythonexe = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\anaconda3\python.exe"
    
     objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & pythonexe & " " & pythonscript   ' This section gives no errors
     
End If
```

Comment: Originally I just put everything in quotations marks but then the command prompt gave the error that the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect  for the execution path not containing any spaces.  Thus for no spaces in the execution path I only use single quotes and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd.exe has pretty nasty quoting rules. You should, however, be able to quote both the Python interpreter path and the script in such a way that it will work consistently whether or not there is a space in the username. Try something like this:

```vb
Dim objShell As Object
Dim pythonexe As String
Dim pythonscript As String
Dim Username As String
Dim cmd As String
'Double-quote character
Dim dq As String: dq = Chr(34)

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Username = "Some name with or without spaces" 'dependent on the user input

pythonexe = dq & "C:\Users\" & Username & "\anaconda3\python.exe" & dq
pythonscript = dq & "C:\Users\" & Username & "\........py" & dq

cmd = "cmd /k " & dq & pythonexe & " " & pythonscript & dq
Debug.Print "Running command (" & cmd & ")"
objShell.Run cmd
```

The correctly-quoted command should look something like this (the Debug line prints it to the Immediate Window for debugging purposes):

```
cmd /k ""C:\Users\Claire Watson\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Claire Watson\.........py""
```

Comment: Colleagues finally had time to test it and it worked.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, because you have not defined a value for your username. The problem is not that the pythonexe path is invalid.

Try to add

```
Username = "Claire Watson"
```

And it should work.

Comment: I just did not add the username definition in the example code because it changes depending on the input, will not always be "Claire Watson" can also be "Eric" with no spaces.  As I mentioned if the code does not have spaces in the path it works fine using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: don't have python for testing so this is my best last attempt...

I find a token-replacement approach easier:

```vba
Dim Username As String, cmd, root, qt

Username = "Some User"                        'dependent on the user input
qt = IIf(InStr(Username, " ") > 0, """", "")  'might need quotes

root = qt & "C:\Users\" & Username & "\"      'root directory with ending \

cmd = "cmd /k <python> <script> "  'cmd template with tokens

'replace tokens with values
cmd = Replace(cmd, "<python>", root & "anaconda3\python.exe" & qt)
cmd = Replace(cmd, "<script>", root & "blah.py" & qt)

Debug.Print cmd
'CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run cmd
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code.  Unfortunately I am running into the same problems.  It I use the first root input where the spaces are replaced with `"^ "`, the command prompt says `C:\Users\Claire: can't open file 'Watson\anaconda3\python.exe': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` .  If I use the `%UserProfile%` directly I get `'C:\Users\Claire' is not recognized as an internal or external command...` So still it is struggling with the spaces and without the spaces it works perfectly.

Comment: Edited above if that doesn't work I don't know what else to try...