# vbaShellRun for Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am running a macro from Excel that calls a python script. I have Python 3.11.5 installed in one location on my PC and 3.12.1 installed at another. When I call the script using 3.11.5

```
vbaShell.Run """C:\Python311\python.exe""" & " " & """D:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\python\getDataTests.py""" & " " & """" & Workbook & """" & " " & """" & path & """"
```

It runs without any issue. But when I run it with 3.12.1

```
vbaShell.Run """C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe""" & " " & """D:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\python\getDataTests.py""" & " " & """" & Workbook & """" & " " & """" & path & """"
```

I see the python shell flash and then nothing, I'm looking for some help troubleshooting since I am not getting an error message and the shell immediately closes. Also any suggestions as to why 3.11 would work but not 3.12. There shouldn't be any compatibility issues within the .py script I am calling.

Comment: Are you running a script though?  It looks like you're just calling the python executable...

Comment: You can use the approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66142478/478884 to keep the window open so you can check for errors before closing...

Comment: After I call python.exe I call the file path for script.py along with some arguments. cmd /k does not work with either 3.11 or 3.12, I'm guessing I'd have to make some edits to get it working with cmd. Since it does work with 3.11 as it is, I'd prefer not to have to re-write, but if it comes down to it, I will.

Comment: Where in your posted code is the path to the script you're running though?

Comment: Apologies I thought I had pasted the whole snippet I have updated. I am calling a script with some arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a python package issue, but since I was not getting any error messages this was hard to determine. I ran the python script from cmd outside of excel and finally got an error.

Had to make sure that I pip installed the packages for 3.12 since they were only installed for 3.11. Woohooops.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub tester()

    Const EXE_PATH As String = "C:\Python\Python39-32\python.exe"
    Const SCRIPT_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\VBA\test.py"

    'keep cmd window open - no args
    RunScriptWithArgs EXE_PATH, SCRIPT_PATH, True
    
    'keep cmd window open - 2 args
    RunScriptWithArgs EXE_PATH, SCRIPT_PATH, True, "Arg1 Here", "Arg2Here"
    
    'same again but close cmd after execution
    RunScriptWithArgs EXE_PATH, SCRIPT_PATH, False, "Arg1 Here", "Arg2Here"

End Sub


Sub RunScriptWithArgs(exePath As String, scriptPath As String, _
                      keepOpen As Boolean, ParamArray args())

    Dim cmd As String, arg, allArgs
    cmd = "cmd " & IIf(keepOpen, "/k", "/c") & " "" ""<exe>"" ""<script>"" <args> """
    cmd = Replace(cmd, "<exe>", exePath)
    cmd = Replace(cmd, "<script>", scriptPath)
    For Each arg In args
        allArgs = allArgs & " """ & arg & """"
    Next arg
    cmd = Replace(cmd, "<args>", allArgs)
    'Debug.Print cmd
    VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run cmd, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Python script (just prints any script arguments to stdout):

```python
import sys
print (sys.argv[1:]);
```

Output:

[image]