# How To Debug Python Code Running Shell Being Called in VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell, debugging

Just joined a company and was asked to fix a tool an old engineer made in VBA. Works fine on every one else's computer except for this one. The folders and all necessary info were copied over.

Everything seems to be working correctly in the code, the only part I can't see is when VBA calls shell to run a python script located in a txt file. In the VBA debugger, stepping over throws no errors, but I want to see exactly what's going in with that code. How can I debug this or see the shell working through the python code line by line?

Tried downloading an older version of python since that was the only noticeable difference... not sure what else to do.

Comment: Post your code if you want help with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77782355/478884 for how to keep the cmd window open after running an external script/program

Answer (score 0):

If you want to step through the Python code line by line, you could launch the script with Python's debugger. It's very primitive compared to VBA's, but it will do the job.

If your VBA code launches the Python script using something like:

`Shell "python3 my_script.py"`

change it to invoke the pdb debugger:

`Shell "python3 -m pdb my_script.py"`

When the script launches in a command prompt, type `step` at the `(Pdb)` prompt to step through the first line of the script. Then just keep pressing enter to repeat the command and step through the rest of it.

Type `help` for a list of commands and see the [pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for more information.