# How to keep shell open when running VBA code?

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell, error-handling

I am trying to debug some code a coworker wrote using VBA. I can't find anything wrong with the VBA, but he does call Shell to run a python script. I want to be able to see what's going on while the python is running, but I'm not sure how I can keep the shell open.

```
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

// Code here that sets the pythonPath, scriptPath, and Exam Number correctly.

objShell.Run pythonPath & " " & scriptPath & " " & tb_ExamNumber.Text, 1, True
```

Is there like a ..... objShell.RunWhileKeepingShellOpen kinda thing? :) Obviously not that specific, but would love some help here.

Or, if anyone has a good idea how I can debug outside of VBA that would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: why the python flag ? this is a vba question.

Comment: Already gave you a suggestion at your previous post - instead of abandoning that one, you could edit it to add the VBA there...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220349/how-to-debug-python-code-running-shell-being-called-in-vba